# Difference between 店{みせ} and 店{てん}舗{ぽ}

Tags: word-choice, wago-and-kango

What is the difference between 店{みせ} and 店{てん}舗{ぽ}? Both mean shop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, there is no real difference in meaning between the words. Both mean 'shop' or 'store'.

As for the tone of the words, you could argue that 店 is more commonly used in spoken Japanese and that 店舗 is slightly more formal sounding, making it more likely to be seen in written Japanese.

Conceptually, there is also an argument that 店 refers more to the 'store' as an abstract idea and that 店舗 refers to the 'store' as the physical building. But I doubt it makes any difference in practice, even if true.